# Liquid to solid crystal when exposed to air

Tags: liquid-crystals

Im working on a prototype weapon based on the [needler from the Halo series](https://youtu.be/-SdRoTj5u-Y). And yes while I do realize that this game series is fantasy, I still find it fun to try and recreate working versions of what is in the game.

I have a concept worked out to keep the crystalline ammunition in a liquid tank and then use compressed air to fire. The liquid will be pushed through perforated holes to for the crystal ammunition. But I don't know of any chemical or compound that turns from liquid to solid, preferably crystalline when exposed to air. If someone could help me with such a substance I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Science fiction actually; more importantly http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Type-33_Guided_Munitions_Launcher says nothing about liquid, needles are supposedly as ready to be fired as any ammo. They're just very advanced smart munitions, a bit similar to [airburst round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airburst_round) but rather penetrating.